# Multiple subscribers to the same event

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to make a system for handling user settings(bunch of controls). The same settings will be implemented two times for two different environments and will control the same logic and contain the same properties. When user change value of some control in the first settings, some changes are made in the program logic and additionaly a control that handles the same property from second settings should be updated. 
Simple diagram:
[image]

So it looks like there are two subscribers(Settings A & B) and three listeners(Settings A & B, Event Handler) for single event .

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Sounds like you are right on the edge of switching over to a [Message Bus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647328.aspx) system, however for just 3 things it is likely not worth the effort. See the [Event Agitator in Prism](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx) for a example.

Comment: Looks like Event Aggregator is what I need. Thanks for point right pattern.

Comment: Turned my comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is the Event Agitator pattern. The Microsoft library Prism [has one built in](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx) that is commonly used. Get the [Prism.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Core/) nuget package to get a pre-made [`PubSubEvent`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Events/PubSubEvent.cs) class that implements it for you.

Comment: I can't use Prism, my target API is .net 2.0

Comment: Being 2.0 this will be hard to correctly implement yourself being that [`WeakEventManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) requires 3.0 at minimum (it is still doable, but you are at a much higher risk of memory leaks if you forget to unsubscribe from the event manager). If you don't mind me asking, why can't you target 3.5? It uses the same CLR as 2.0.

Comment: This is unity3d application. Do you know any tutorial that explains how to implement this pattern by yourself?

Comment: Unity3d has access to .NET 3.5. Also, unity3d has [a Event Agitator built in](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MessagingSystem.html) to it, you don't need to implement it yourself.